# Get all child contexts of a NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, core-data, magicalrecord

In a Core Data model there are three Entities `A`, `B` and `C` where `A` can have a relation to `B` and/or `C`.

For certain reasons `B` and `C` are being created in a child context (they both share the *same* child context) of `A`s context. So there is *one* parent context (used by `A`) having *one* child context (used by `B` and `C`).

Now I need to

1. fetch all `A`s and
2. fetch all `B`s (or `C`s).

I'm using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to interact with CoreData, so (1) is pretty easy to achieve:

```
NSArray *all_As = [A findAll];
```

To achieve (2), I could now use that I know `A`'s context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *contextOfA = a.managedObjectContext
```

where `a` is an instance of `A`. Note that due to the way my app is designed, there is always an `a` which can be used to get all `B` an `C` instances (in other words: I don't need to access `B` and `C` without `A`). As stated above, there doesn't have to be a relation between `A` and `B` (and `C`). In the end, `a` doesn't even have to exist (`b` and `c` can live without `a`).

But I do know, that `B` and `C` live in `A`'s child context.

So basically I just need to get `a.managedObjectContext`'s child context and perform a fetch request on that child context:

```
NSArrray *all_Bs = [B findAllInContext: a.managedObjectContext.childContext]
```

But **how can I access `a.managedObjectContext.childContext`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply call this?

```
NSArray *all_Bs = [B findAll];
```

MR should be able to deal with the contexts by itself if they are not mentioned.

If that does not work - you cannot predict if it will using third party frameworks - why don't you simply keep a reference to you child context around and use that when fetching `B`?

*(Why you would use something like MR is beyond me. It does make things quite a bit more complicated once you are actually using the advanced features of Core Data.)*

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't return the desired result. I guess that's because of the way I'm saving objects (see clarification in my original post). Concerning your second suggestion, how would I find out the child context of an object after relaunching the app? I mean, in this situation I can't create a reference because I don't know what to reference, right?

Comment: I originally didn't use MR, but implemented it after struggling with iCloud in combination with Core Data. MR simplifies that stuff dramatically. But even simple tasks like getting all entities are much simpler using MR.

Comment: Did I do that? Then I misunderstood your suggestion, sorry about that. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem:

In my `AppDelegate`, I put a variable `NSManagedObjectContext *tempObjectContext;`. When I'm now adding an `A` object, I'm adding it to this `tempObjectContext`.

As stated in my original post, this `a` is permanently existing when adding a new `B` or `C` object. But `B` and `C` don't have to get a relation with  `a`. Therefore I'm adding those `B` and `C` objects into `tempObjectContext` as well.

Now, when I want to save a `B` or `C` object, I save them into `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]` and delete them from `tempObjectContext`:

```
B *finalObject = [B createInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]];
NSDictionary *attributes = [[B entityDescription] attributesByName];
[finalObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[self.temp dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[attributes allKeys]]];

[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] insertObject:finalObject];

[self.mainDelegate.tempObjectContext deleteObject:self.temp];
```

So, why am I doing all that? Simple: When I would put all `A`, `B` and `C` into the same object, then create an `a` and afterwards `b`, I couldn't save `b` without saving `a` (as they all resist in the same context). Using separate contexts solve this problem.